# CertStream Javascript gives error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up a HTML page that want to use the data from [CertStream](https://certstream.calidog.io).

The Javascript library is located at https://github.com/CaliDog/certstream-js

In the install instructions it says " if you're using this in the browser, just add dist/certstream.min.js to a  tag, and interact with it as normal!".

I have therefor created a HTML page that uses this tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Certstream</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UFT-8" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>CertStream</h1>

<!-- CertStream script -->
    <script src="dist/certstream.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    const CertStreamClient = require('certstream');

    let client = new CertStreamClient(function(message){
        console.log("Received -> ", message)
    });

    client.connect();

    </script>
<!-- //CertStream script -->


</body>
</html>
```

But I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>  http://localhost/certstream-js/test.html:15

certstream.min.js is located on in the folder "dist":

```
!function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=t():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],t):"object"==typeof exports?exports.CertStream=t():e.CertStream=t()}(this,function(){return function(e){function t(o){if(n[o])return n[o].exports;var c=n[o]={exports:{},id:o,loaded:!1};return e[o].call(c.exports,c,c.exports,t),c.loaded=!0,c.exports}var n={};return t.m=e,t.c=n,t.p="",t(0)}([function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(e){return e&&e.__esModule?e:{default:e}}function c(e,t){if(!(e instanceof t))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0});var r=function(){function e(e,t){for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){var o=t[n];o.enumerable=o.enumerable||!1,o.configurable=!0,"value"in o&&(o.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(e,o.key,o)}}return function(t,n,o){return n&&e(t.prototype,n),o&&e(t,o),t}}(),i=n(1),s=o(i),a=function(){function e(t){var n=arguments.length>1&&void 0!==arguments[1]&&arguments[1];c(this,e),this.context={},this.callback=t,this.skipHeartbeats=n}return r(e,[{key:"connect",value:function(){var e=this;console.log("Connecting..."),this.ws=new s.default("wss://certstream.calidog.io/"),console.log("Created ws -> ",this.ws),this.ws.onmessage=function(t){console.log("onmessage called!");var n=JSON.parse(t.data);"heartbeat"===n.message_type&&e.skipHeartbeats||e.callback(t,e.context)},this.ws.onopen=function(){console.log("Connection established to certstream! Waiting for messages...")},this.ws.open()}}]),e}();t.default=a},function(e,t,n){var o,c,r;!function(n,i){c=[],o=i,r="function"==typeof o?o.apply(t,c):o,!(void 0!==r&&(e.exports=r))}(this,function(){function e(t,n,o){function c(e,t){var n=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");return n.initCustomEvent(e,!1,!1,t),n}var r={debug:!1,automaticOpen:!0,reconnectInterval:1e3,maxReconnectInterval:3e4,reconnectDecay:1.5,timeoutInterval:2e3,maxReconnectAttempts:null};o||(o={});for(var i in r)"undefined"!=typeof o[i]?this[i]=o[i]:this[i]=r[i];this.url=t,this.reconnectAttempts=0,this.readyState=WebSocket.CONNECTING,this.protocol=null;var s,a=this,u=!1,l=!1,d=document.createElement("div");d.addEventListener("open",function(e){a.onopen(e)}),d.addEventListener("close",function(e){a.onclose(e)}),d.addEventListener("connecting",function(e){a.onconnecting(e)}),d.addEventListener("message",function(e){a.onmessage(e)}),d.addEventListener("error",function(e){a.onerror(e)}),this.addEventListener=d.addEventListener.bind(d),this.removeEventListener=d.removeEventListener.bind(d),this.dispatchEvent=d.dispatchEvent.bind(d),this.open=function(t){if(s=new WebSocket(a.url,n||[]),t){if(this.maxReconnectAttempts&&this.reconnectAttempts>this.maxReconnectAttempts)return}else d.dispatchEvent(c("connecting")),this.reconnectAttempts=0;(a.debug||e.debugAll)&&console.debug("ReconnectingWebSocket","attempt-connect",a.url);var o=s,r=setTimeout(function(){(a.debug||e.debugAll)&&console.debug("ReconnectingWebSocket","connection-timeout",a.url),l=!0,o.close(),l=!1},a.timeoutInterval);s.onopen=function(n){clearTimeout(r),(a.debug||e.debugAll)&&console.debug("ReconnectingWebSocket","onopen",a.url),a.protocol=s.protocol,a.readyState=WebSocket.OPEN,a.reconnectAttempts=0;var o=c("open");o.isReconnect=t,t=!1,d.dispatchEvent(o)},s.onclose=function(n){if(clearTimeout(r),s=null,u)a.readyState=WebSocket.CLOSED,d.dispatchEvent(c("close"));else{a.readyState=WebSocket.CONNECTING;var o=c("connecting");o.code=n.code,o.reason=n.reason,o.wasClean=n.wasClean,d.dispatchEvent(o),t||l||((a.debug||e.debugAll)&&console.debug("ReconnectingWebSocket","onclose",a.url),d.dispatchEvent(c("close")));var r=a.reconnectInterval*Math.pow(a.reconnectDecay,a.reconnectAttempts);setTimeout(function(){a.reconnectAttempts++,a.open(!0)},r>a.maxReconnectInterval?a.maxReconnectInterval:r)}},s.onmessage=function(t){(a.debug||e.debugAll)&&console.debug("ReconnectingWebSocket","onmessage",a.url,t.data);var n=c("message");n.data=t.data,d.dispatchEvent(n)},s.onerror=function(t){(a.debug||e.debugAll)&&console.debug("ReconnectingWebSocket","onerror",a.url,t),d.dispatchEvent(c("error"))}},1==this.automaticOpen&&this.open(!1),this.send=function(t){if(s)return(a.debug||e.debugAll)&&console.debug("ReconnectingWebSocket","send",a.url,t),s.send(t);throw"INVALID_STATE_ERR : Pausing to reconnect websocket"},this.close=function(e,t){"undefined"==typeof e&&(e=1e3),u=!0,s&&s.close(e,t)},this.refresh=function(){s&&s.close()}}if("WebSocket"in window)return e.prototype.onopen=function(e){},e.prototype.onclose=function(e){},e.prototype.onconnecting=function(e){},e.prototype.onmessage=function(e){},e.prototype.onerror=function(e){},e.debugAll=!1,e.CONNECTING=WebSocket.CONNECTING,e.OPEN=WebSocket.OPEN,e.CLOSING=WebSocket.CLOSING,e.CLOSED=WebSocket.CLOSED,e})}])});
//# sourceMappingURL=certstream.min.js.map
```

Comment: Where is your include to 'require'?

Comment: Steve: I dont understand the question.

Comment: Answer is clarified by - T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they mean by

> ...if you're using this in the browser, just add dist/certstream.min.js to a tag, and interact with it as normal!

...is that you **don't** need the `require` call (`require` is CommonJS, not standard JavaScript, and not provided by default on browsers). If you just include the script file in your page, it defines a global `CertStream` object with a `default` property providing the default export of the module. *(I suspected this was the case, so I grabbed a copy and tried it.)*

The docs could be clearer. In particular, it looks like after including the library in the browser, you have to use `CertStream.default` rather than `CertStreamClient`. I'd probably do that by doing this up-front:

```
const CertStreamClient = CertStream.default;
```

(It's too bad they don't provide a native JavaScript module [ESM] file in their `dist` folder.)

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand it in general either. What would be the next steps to make it run?

Comment: @Reporter - `CertStream.default` is a function. As far as I can tell, it's the `CertStreamClient` function, so `const CertStreamClient = CertStream.default` and then follow the documenation, I think, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up into certstream.js module in the dist folder and it is a UMD module. Basically, a UMD module is a JavaScript file that tries to guess at runtime which module system it’s being used in, and then it acts as that kind of module. So you can load the file in a plain `<script>`, or you can load it from an AMD module loader, or you can load it as a Node.js module, and it will always do something sensible.

[image]

In your code since you have already loaded the module using `<script>` tag, the global `CertStream` object can be directly used without requiring the module again.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me to improve my knowlegde in general.